# Git: false merge conflicts?

Tags: git, git-merge

I've been using git for a few years, and every once in a while when doing a merge, git reports some bizarre conflicts. Here's an example of an .htaccess file, from when I merged in the new 7.24 release of Drupal core:

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
<<<<<<< HEAD
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Hide important scripts from malicious users.
<FilesMatch "^(autoinstall\.php|install\.php|update\.php)$">
=======
>>>>>>> 7.24
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

How is there a conflict here? It's not even a potential case of whitespace/endline differences: there's simply **nothing** in the 7.24 section of the conflict.

Why is git complaining about this? I'm probably misunderstanding something fundamental...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t detemine the conflict looking only at two sides.  A conflict occurs when both sides make different changes from the common ancestor.

The fact that there is “nothing” on one side doesn’t matter - there *was* something in the ancestor, and both sides changed it.

You can get more data about the conflict by showing the ancestor in conflict files; you can set:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Which will show you all three sides of the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Git selects a shared ancestor for its merges:

```
0 
|_________
    |     |
    a     b
    |_____|_
            |
            M
```

If git detects that both `a` and `b` are changes from `0`, this causes a merge issue preventing it from automatically producing the merged file `M`.

Have you looked at it in a proper 3-way merge tool like [p4merge](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools)? It may help show you what git thinks is the shared ancestor and what it perceives as the conflicting change.

Comment: You can also enable "git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3" to see the common ancestor in your merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a decent explanation of what’s likely going on with your bogus conflicts here: [The criss-cross merge case (2005-04-28)](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0504/2279.html)

> ```
> A
> |\
> | \
> |  \
> |   \
> |    \
> |     \
> |      \
> B8      C3
> |\     /|
> | \   / |
> |  \ /  |
> |   X   |
> |  / \  |
> | /   \ |
> |/     \|
> D8      E3
>  \      |
>   \     |
>    \    |
>     \   |
>      \  |
>       \ |
>        \|
>         ?
> ```
>
> […]
>
> The problem is that there's no single ancestor for the three-way merge
>   which does the right thing.

Incidentally, that post was written by Bram Cohen – one of the authors of BitTorrent. He later tried to develop [his own alternative to Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeville) that he hoped would get around these sorts of issues. His analysis of the problem is spot on, but I don’t think he was ever able to really solve it. There are interesting reasons behind why this is probably unsolvable, but a StackOverflow post isn’t the right place for that rabbit hole.